# Does Make create rules for the dependencies if they are not available?

Tags: gcc, makefile

The below makefile does not have target for making OBJECTS but still the make is forming the rule and makes the OBJECTS and makes the final all.exe. I am not sure how does it work. Does make have mechanism to create rules if they are not available in the makefile for the dependencies?

```
SOURCE=$(wildcard Source/\*.cpp)
TEST=$(wildcard Source/Tests/\*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCE:.cpp=.o) $(TEST:.cpp=.o)
CXXFLAGS= -O3 -fstack-usage -MMD

all:$(OBJECTS)
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

print::
    @echo $(SOURCE)
    @echo $(OBJECTS)
    @echo $(TEST)

clean:
    rm -rf Source/*.o Source/Tests/*.o *.exe
```

Console Output:

```
$ make
g++ -O3 -fstack-usage -MMD   -c -o Source/main.o Source/main.cpp
g++ -O3 -fstack-usage -MMD   -c -o Source/Tests/TestList.o Source/Tests/TestList.cpp
g++ -O3 -fstack-usage -MMD   -c -o Source/Tests/TestLinkedlist.o Source/Tests/TestLinkedlist.cpp
g++ -O3 -fstack-usage -MMD -o all Source/main.o Source/Tests/TestList.o Source/Tests/TestLinkedlist.o
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: Make does indeed have some [default rules](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_09).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GNU make has a full suite of built-in rules.

See the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist it was a helpful

Comment: You can also run `make -p -f/dev/null` to see the full database of built-in rules and variables: the manual doesn't cover them all.